# add new email account to outlook2007 programmatically using c#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2007, configure

All I was wondering if there was a way to run a program and add a spesific email account (with all the correct port settings and whatnot) to outlook2007

I have several users in the feild that seem incapable of doing this themselfs or even doing it with me walking them threw it over the phone

I would love to just email them a program and they run it and it just configures it for them.

How to do this from .net (c#)?

Answer (score 4):

From managed code ther is no way via the OOM but redemption has a [Profman lib](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profiles.htm).
I would also say check out the Office Customization Tool in the 2007 Office system (Ok thats not via code :) but may be simpler for you to use )

Comment: what about a bat file or something along thouse lines?

Comment: Profman will be the way to go then make a solution that takes command pramas for your setings or and xml file. Customization Tool does also allow you a way to set up a profile file.

Comment: +1 mentioning the OCT 2007 tool, this is what he probably really needs.